# Upgrade from Tridon 2009 to Tridion 2013

Tags: tridion

Can anyone help me is there any possiblity to upgrade Tridion 2009 CME db to Tridion 2013 CME db? If yes what are those steps?

Thanks & regards,
Hiren Mistry

Comment: Wanted to understand why is it off track topic?

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade the Tridion 2009 SP1 database to Tridion 2013. The process is documented in the online manual: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/idheading-158932928 (login required).

Answer (score 1):

Hiren.   I recommend that you raise questions over at the [Tridion Stack Exchange](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/) site.

The Tridion 2013 [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_D9DC76FF96CC408EBB447B192CE1C0C0) (login required) says:

> You can upgrade to SDL Tridion 2013 from SDL Tridion 2009 SP1, SDL
>   Tridion 2011 SP1, SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 or SDL Tridion 2011 SP1
>   HR2.

There is a dedicated section on [Upgrading Content Manager Databases](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/idheading-158932928) (login required), which covers all of the necessary steps.

If you are on Tridion 2009 (not SP1), then you will probably have to upgrade the CM database in two steps.